# XML error validator

Tags: xml

I've problem with XML file and I'm not able to solve it. Could you please help me? XML validator shows: "error on line 15969 at column 2: Extra content at the end of the document). Part of the problem code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<results trackingurl="GPS">
<results>
    <object id="535">
     <title><![CDATA[Title blablabla...]]></title>
         <thumbnail><![CDATA[http://vsohbrno.chudst.cz/poi_obrazek.png]]></thumbnail>
         <icon><![CDATA[http://vsohbrno.chudst.cz/poi_obrazek.png]]></icon>
         <location>
         <lat>50.9838275000</lat>
         <lon>14.2881458000</lon>
         <alt>0</alt>
         </location>
         <popup>
         <description><![CDATA[Description blablabla...]]></description>
         <buttons>
             <button id="url" name="Website"><![CDATA[http://www.leag.cz]]></button>
         </buttons>
         </popup>
    </object>
</results>
```

I generate the code with php:

```
while ($radek = mysql_fetch_array($results))
{

$text = '  
 <object id="'. $radek['id'] .'">
  <title><![CDATA['. $radek['title'] .']]></title>
    <thumbnail><![CDATA['. $radek['imageURL'] .']]></thumbnail>
    <icon><![CDATA['. $radek['imageURL'] .']]></icon>
    <location>
        <lat>'. $radek['lat'] .'</lat>
        <lon>'. $radek['lon'] .'</lon>
        <alt>0</alt>
    </location>
    <popup>
        <description><![CDATA['. $radek['line2'] . ' ' .  $radek['attribution'] .']]></description>
        <buttons>
            <button id="url" name="Website"><![CDATA[http://www.leag.cz]]></button>
    </buttons>
    </popup>
 </object>
';                             

$file= fopen("poi_junaio.xml", "a+");
fwrite($file, $text);
fclose($file);
}
$end= '</results>';
$file= fopen("poi_junaio.xml", "a+");
fwrite($file, $end);
fclose($file);
```

Thanks for any solution!

Comment: Why are there in your code two open tag of a result element, and only one close tag? –

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<results trackingurl="GPS">
  <results>
    ...
  </results>
</results>
```

The seconds closing tag for 'results' is missing or you dont need the second 'results' start tag

Comment: Yep. It was it. I tried to put two </results> into the XML file before, however Junaio validator (http://dev.junaio.com/) in this case just "loaded"... and loaded... and still it's loading and makes nothing. When I put here just one </result>, Junaio validator gave me error in a few secs. Well, now it's the question for junaio forum. Jochim & Carlo, thank you, it's working :)